# Getting deadlock when using ExecuteReaderAsync

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, deadlock, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm trying to use the async pattern to execute a SQL command and return a DataTable.
Can someone please advice how to solve this problem?

This is my code:

```
    private static async Task<DataTable> ExecuteAsync(Connections connection, SqlBuilder sql)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectstring(connection)))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.Query, conn))
            {
                foreach (var parameter in sql.ColumnValues.Where(d => !d.Name.StartsWith("#")))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Name, parameter.Value);
                }

                //Why am I getting a deadlock when executing the next line?
                using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: Are you sure it is a deadlock not just timing out on the server connection?

Comment: How do you know you have a deadlock? You may be connecting to the wrong server, have a slow connection or returning too much data. Does the method work if you use the synchronous methods?

Comment: You'll need to characterize "deadlock".  It is also an exception that SQL Server can generate.  Which I suspect is the real problem.

Comment: When running this as a synchronous call, I get a response back after a second or two. When running as async, it all stops. When debugging, the line where it stops is when reading into the SqlDataReader

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect you are using `Wait` or `Result` further up your call stack. This [causes a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) if called from a UI thread, as I describe on my blog.

Comment: Even after being "100% sure" of not using any Result, I found it hidden in my code. Thank you...